# React collect child component data on some event from the parent component

Tags: reactjs

In react best practice is Data flow from parent to child, event's will be passed from child to parent.

[image: How to a avoid anti pattern for this UI?]

In this UI we have a parent component which contains 2 child components with forms. We now have to gather data from child components when the user clicks on the submit button in the parent.

Possible solutions (Bad solutions | anti pattern):

1. Pass ref from child and trigger child method from parent to collect data (Accessing child method from parent not a good idea)

```
 <Parent>
    onFormData(data) {
     //here collect data from child
    }

    onSubmit() {
      //Trigger a method onData in child
      aRef.collectData()
    }

    <child-A ref={aRef} onData={onFormData}></Child-A>
    <Child-B ref={bRef} onData={onFormData}></Child-B>
    
    <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</Submit> 
</Parent>
```

2. Bind a props to child, on submit click change value of prop with dummy value. Observe same prop in useEffect hook ( Really bad solution)

```
 <Parent>
    onFormData(data) {
     //here collect data from child
    }

    onSubmit() {
      //update randomValue, which will be observed in useEffect that calls onData method from child
      randomValue = Math.random();
    }

    <child-A triggerSubmit={randomValue} onData={onFormData}></Child-A>
    <Child-B triggerSubmit={randomValue} onData={onFormData}></Child-B>
    
    <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</Submit> 
</Parent>
```

Is there any other best approach for handling these scenario?  How to a  avoid anti pattern for this UI?

Comment: To better answer the question, could you clarify why you need two forms instead of one?

Comment: here even it could be just one form.. This is a just a sample example to explain the problem.. The problem here is how to notify child to trigger event when submit button is in parent...

Comment: Have you found any nice solution to the problem?

Answer (score 3):

there is the third option (which is the standard way): you don't collect data, you pass your `formData` and `setFormData` to each `Child` as props. using [lift state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) approach.

Each `Child` populates its input values with `formData` and uses `setFormData` to update `formData` that lives on `Parent`. Finally,  at on submit you only have to set `formData`to you request call.

below an example:

```
const ChildA = ({ formData, setFormData }) => {
  const { name, age } = formData
  const onChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => { // destructuring 'name' and 'value'
    setFormData(formData => ({ ...formData, [name]: value })) // spread formData, update field with 'name' key
  }
  return (
    <>
      <label>Name<input type="text" onChange={onChange} name="name" value={name} /></label>
     <label>Age<input type="number" onChange={onChange} name="age" value={age} /></label>
    </>
  );
}

const ChildB = ({ formData, setFormData }) => {
  const { email, acceptTerms } = formData
  const onChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setFormData(formData => ({ ...formData, [name]: value }))
  }

  const onClick = ({ target: { name, checked } }) => {
    setFormData(formData => ({ ...formData, [name]: checked }))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label>email<input type="email" onChange={onChange} name="email" value={email} /></label>
      <label>Accept Terms<input type="checkbox" onChange={onClick} name="acceptTerms" checked={acceptTerms} /></label>
    </>
  );
}


const Parent = () => {
  // used one formData. you could break down into more if you prefer
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ name: '', age: null, acceptTerms: false, email: undefined }) 

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // here you implement logic to submit form
    console.log(formData)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ChildA formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />
      <ChildB formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />
      <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button> 
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: but what if we are using a 3rd party library like hookform or formik? those case we will collect the data only once..

Comment: @ksh you don't collect data only once regardless if you use a 3rd party form lib. it's has its tweeks given each lib implementation, but the form values are always updated. and you should have them available on submit

Comment: let's forget this example... Please help me to understand is it not possible to trigger event's from parent to child? or is it just bad practice in react

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is to "lift the state up" to the parent. This means I would not break the natural React flow, that is passing props from the parent to the children. Following your example, I would put ALL the logic in the parent (submit function, form state, etc)

```
Const Parent = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({})

  const onSubmitForm = () => {
      // send formData to somewhere
  }

  return (
      <ChildrenForm onChange={setFormData} formData={formData} />
      <button onSubmit={() => onSubmitForm()}>my button</button>
  )
}
```

Now I would use the `onChange` function inside the Children to update the `formData` everytime an input in the ChildrenForm changes. So all my state will be in the parent and I don't need to worry about having to pass everything up, from children to parent (antipattern as you mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Approach 2) with random is Not Really So Bad! And only this one preserves encapsulation not involving DOM/withRef round trip. Suggested Up State way leads to hard coded dependency and undermines whole idea of re-usability. The only thing I have to mention is: code as it was typed above will not work - because usual variables will not trigger. Right way to make it like that:

```
// Parent component

let [randomValue, setRandomValue] = React.useState(Math.random());
const onSubmit = () => { 
  setRandomValue(Math.random());
  console.log("click");
}
const onFormData  = data => {
  console.log(`${data}`);
}
...
<Child triggerSubmit={randomValue} onData={onFormData}/>

// Child component

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("child id here");
  prop.onData(`Hey Ho! Lets go!`)
}, [prop.triggerSubmit]);
```

At least this works for me!